# iPhone, get playlists from Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

How i can get list of user playlists from code? In CocoaTouch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is solution:

```
MPMediaQuery *playlistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
NSArray *playlists = [playlistsQuery collections];
```

:)

Answer (score 11):

```
MPMediaQuery *myPlaylistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];

NSArray *playlists = [myPlaylistsQuery collections];

for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in playlists) {
    NSLog (@"%@", [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);
    NSArray *songs = [playlist items];
    for (MPMediaItem *song in songs) {
        NSString *songTitle =
            [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        NSLog (@"\t\t%@", songTitle);
    }
}
```